# How to fix 'Possible unintended interpolation of $\ in regex'?

Tags: regex, perl

At work I have this old script whose author is no longer with the company. The script itself runs perfectly fine, but everytime I run it, I get the following warning:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of $\ in regex at /bin/script line 223.
Possible unintended interpolation of $\ in regex at /bin/script line 226.
```

The two lines I marked are the corresponding ones:

```
sub get_modul {

...

    open (IN, "path/to/file") || Pl_Fatal ("Error trying to open file");
    $tempvar = <IN>;
    close (IN);
    @temp = split(":", $tempvar);
    if ($#temp != 1) {
       $MODUL =~ s/$\$2\///;   # <--
    }
    else {
        $MODUL =~ s/$\$0\///;  # <--
    }
}
```

As I receive a warning for both lines that exclude each other I think it does not have to do anything with the input but just in case:

the script parses `:server:user@host:/path/to/rep` or `/path/to/rep` and the output in both cases is `/path/to/rep`.

I'm running Perl v5.18.2 if that's of any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is explained in [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html).

> **Possible unintended interpolation of $\ in regex**
>
> (W ambiguous) You said something like `m/$\/` in a regex. The regex `m/foo$\s+bar/m` translates to: match the word 'foo', the output record separator (see $\ in perlvar) and the letter 's' (one time or more) followed by the word 'bar'.
>
> If this is what you intended then you can silence the warning by using `m/${\}/` (for example: `m/foo${\}s+bar/`).
>
> If instead you intended to match the word 'foo' at the end of the line followed by whitespace and the word 'bar' on the next line then you can use `m/$(?)\/` (for example: `m/foo$(?)\s+bar/`).

`$\` is the output record separator. It's what Perl automatically appends to anything that you output using `print()`. The default value is `undef`.

So, in your regex it's *probably* doing nothing (as `undef` becomes an empty string when used in a string). But it's impossible to be sure without seeing the rest of the code - as you might change the value of `$\` elsewhere in the program.